# Javascript - use value from array for map icon colour

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a custom map using Apple MapKit JS and the data for the map icons and callouts is coming from an array. This is working well but all marker icons use the same colour. I'm using the Custom Callout example from the Apple website where it sets the value for the colour here:

```
    // Landmarks annotations
var annotations = sanFranciscoLandmarks.map(function(landmark) {
    var annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(landmark.coordinate, {
        callout: landmarkAnnotationCallout,
        color: "#c969e0"
    });
    annotation.landmark = landmark;
    return annotation;
});
```

I've modified the array to include a markerColor value as well and was hoping I could reference that to specify the value for the marker icon colour:

```
    // Landmarks data
var sanFranciscoLandmarks = [
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7951315, -122.402986), title: "Transamerica Pyramid", phone: "+1-415-983-5420", url: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/", markerColor: "#c969e0"  },
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7954201, -122.39352), title: "Ferry Building", phone: "+1 (415) 983-8030", url: "http://www.ferrybuildingmarketplace.com", markerColor: "#FF0000" },
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7785538, -122.514035), title: "Cliff House", phone: "+1 (415) 386-3330", url: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/", markerColor: "#00FFFF" }
];
```

I've tried modifying this line:

```
 color: "#c969e0"
```

to:

```
 color: annotation.landmark.markerColor
```

which doesn't work and generates a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'annotation.landmark')` in the browser console.

Is it possible to dynamically reference the marker colour from the markerColor value from the array?

Comment: I think you would just change `color: annotation.landmark.markerColor` to `color: landmark.markerColor` . It's throwing an error because you are trying to reference a property of the `annotation` object before you've finished instantiating the `annotation` object, so at the time, `annotation` is equal to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks that's working well in my tests so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `color: landmark.markerColor` resolved this for me.